# Problem with post like system in angular with firebase

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to build post like system with angular and firebase.I like to get is some user liked some post. I have an likedd variable with true and false values because every time it is undefined, but it doesn't work.Here is the code:

```
liked(pid, uid) {
    this.db.doc('posts/' + pid + '/likes/' + uid).valueChanges().subscribe((data) => {
        if (data.liked == true) {
            this.likedd = true
        } else {
            this.likedd = false
        }
    })
}
```

Here is the data:

```
Post ->
likes ->
likerUid ->
liked -> it can be true or false
```

Comment: What does not work exactly? this.likedd does not change in your template? If it is the case, it won't change due to the Observable return value of subscribe and you can use the async pipe on your template. If you can be more clear, we may help more. Also, you do not need all if-else there. Just use 'this.likedd = data.liked;'

Comment: Every time it is undefined. I use it to know if user liked the post or not.